# Vertx args command line documentation

Tags: vert.x

Where is the full documentation of vert.x command line supported arguments or  option ?

like -cluster -conf

I would like to override my  default log4j.xml using an external file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's on the Vert.x core documentation:

http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_the_vertx_command_line

But Vert.x does not manage logging config.